# Visual Studio 2017 Diameter Circumference and Area, My code won't work

Tags: vb.net

I can't get my program to give me the Diameter Circumference and Area with just the Radius. It keeps telling me

> "'Text' is not a member of 'Double'"

, I don't know what that means. Here is my main code.

```
Dim Radius As Double

Radius = Radius.Text

Diameter.Text = 2 * Radius
Circumference.Text = 2 * 3.14 * Radius
Area.Text = 3.14 * (Radius * Radius)
```

Comment: Not sure in VS, but try `Radius = CDbl(Radius.Text)`

Comment: vba is for Excel,Word,Access not visual studio.  Please read the descriptions of the tags.

Comment: Also I think there should be a proper Pi constant in VS. 3.14 is not accurate enough. In VBA Excel, it is `WorksheetFunction.Pi`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! I figured it out, I was using the name Radius for both a text and a variable, so I decided to name them differently. Also, I had to use the predefined constant **Math.PI** instead of using the actual number. Thank you everyone, I really appreciate your help!!

```
  Dim R As Double
    R = Radius.Text

    Diameter.Text = 2 * R
    Circumference.Text = 2 * Math.PI * R
    Area.Text = Math.PI * (R * R)
```

Answer (score -1):

Cast Radius.Text to int before assign it go Radius